# Cakephp: Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

## Error message

> Error: Cannot use string offset as an array
>   File: C:\wamp\www\itsm\app\Model\TaskAttribute.php
>   Line: 48

### lines of error

```
47    foreach($items as $row){
48          $categoryId = $row['Category']['id'];
49          $item_id =  $row['Item']['id'];
50          $attr_id = $row['Attribute']['id'];
```

## My Method

```
public function getTree($branch_id = NULL){
        $tree = array();
        $items =  $this->find('list',array(
            'fields' => array('ItemAttribute.item_id','ItemAttribute.item_id'),
            'joins' =>array(
                        array(
                            'table' => 'item_attributes',
                            'alias' => 'ItemAttribute',
                            'type' => 'INNER',
                            'conditions' => 'TaskAttribute.item_attribute_id = ItemAttribute.id',
                         ),                 


                ),
                'recursive'=>-1
            )
        );  



        if(isset($items)){
            $assets = $this->Checklist->ChecklistAttribute->AssetAttribute->Asset->getList($branch_id ,array_keys($items));
            //pr($assets);die();
        }

        foreach($items as $row){
            $categoryId = $row['Category']['id'];
            $item_id =  $row['Item']['id'];
            $attr_id = $row['Attribute']['id'];

            if(!isset($tree[$categoryId])){
                $tree[$categoryId] = array('id'=>$categoryId ,'name'=>$row['Category']['name'] ,'Items'=>array());

            }


            $attrib = array('id'=>$row['Attribute']['id'] ,'name'=>$row['Attribute']['name'],'type'=>$row['Attribute']['type']);

            if(isset($items[$item_id])){

                if($asset = ifExist($assets ,$item_id)){
                    if(!isset($tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id])){
                        $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]  = array('id'=>$item_id ,'name'=>$row['Item']['model']);
                    }                       
                    if(!isset($tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets'])){
                        $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets'] = array('id'=>$asset['id'] ,'name'=>$asset['serial'] ,'Attributes'=>array());
                    }
                    if(!isset($tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets']['Attributes'][$attr_id])){
                        $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets']['Attributes'][$attr_id] = $attrib;
                    }
                    if($option_id = ifExist($row ,'AttributeOptions' ,'id')){
                        if(!isset($tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets']['Attributes'][$attr_id]['options'])){
                            $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets']['Attributes'][$attr_id]['options'] = array();
                        }
                        $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets']['Attributes'][$attr_id]['options'][$option_id] = $row['AttributeOptions']['label'];
                    }
                }
            }else{

                if(!isset($tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id])){
                    $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]  = array('id'=>$item_id ,'name'=>$row['Item']['model'] ,'Attributes'=>array());
                }           
                if(!isset($tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Attributes'][$attr_id])){
                    $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Attributes'][$attr_id] = $attrib;
                }       
                if($option_id = ifExist($row ,'AttributeOptions' ,'id')){   
                    if(!isset($tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Assets']['Attributes'][$attr_id]['options'])){
                        $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Attributes'][$attr_id]['options'] = array();
                    }
                    $tree[$categoryId]['Items'][$item_id]['Attributes'][$attr_id]['options'][$option_id] = $row['AttributeOptions']['label'];
                }
            }


        }

            if(isset($tree)){
                foreach($tree as $key=>$items){
                    if(!ifExist($items ,'Items')){
                    unset($tree[$key]);
                }
            }

            return $tree;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you check with `debug($items);` to see what structure the `$items` array has?

Comment: yes checked... its as follows:
array(
 (int) 35 =&gt; &#039;35&#039;,
 (int) 40 =&gt; &#039;40&#039;,
 (int) 50 =&gt; &#039;50&#039;,
 (int) 51 =&gt; &#039;51&#039;,
 (int) 53 =&gt; &#039;53&#039;,
 (int) 54 =&gt; &#039;54&#039;,
 (int) 55 =&gt; &#039;55&#039;,
 (int) 56 =&gt; &#039;56&#039;,

Comment: Dumping entity encoded code, seriously? And isn't it obvious that the array isn't formatted the way your code is expecting it?

Comment: @ndm I used debug for both '$items' and '$row'... they are fetching data.... the problem is with the line  '$categoryId = $row['Category']['id'];'

Comment: The problem is how your data is formatted. Please read the CookBook on [**what a `find('list')` call returns**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list). No offense, but that's CakePHP basics, and SO isn't really the place to teach stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Find list returns a list

This code in the question:

```
$items =  $this->find('list',array(
    'fields' => array('key field','value field')
    ...
));
```

Returns a flat list - i.e. `$items` is of the structure:

```
array(
    'key' => 'value string',
    'key2' => 'value string2',
);
```

As such - attempting to treat `'value string'` as an array results in an error.

```
foreach($items as $item_id => $item_id) {
    //                        ^ It's a string

    // So this won't work:
    // $categoryId = $item_id['Category']['id'];

    $categoryId = ...; // not in the results
    $item_id =  ...; // it's the key and the value returned by find list
    $attr_id = // not in the results
```

As indicated above, 2 of the three bits of info the code tries to obtain aren't in the results at all.

### Use find all to return an array

The simplest solution is just call find all:

```
$items =  $this->find('all',array(
    //'fields' => array('key field','value field')
    ...
));

debug($items);
die;
```

Only restrict the fields returned *after* verifying that all the required data is present.